# Cygwin startup error /usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID

Tags: windows, cygwin, startup

I use cygwin at work to get quick access to unix tools and as an ssh terminal. I recently installed some new Cygwin packages and now when I try and open a terminal it is very slow and gives the following error:

```
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 10519
```

I'm not sure what the error means, but it takes much longer to open a cygwin terminal now than it use to.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be related to my Active Directory username or group memberships. The error went away after running the following command as per [this article](https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2006/10/27/cygwin-users-and-groups/):

```
mkpasswd -l -c > /etc/passwd; mkgroup -l -d > /etc/group
```

This updates the cygwin files with the latest AD user/group information.

Comment: Yes, the command solve the problem BUT you need to have the "last" version installed (after august 2014)

Answer (score 3):

None of the modifications of `/etc/group` nor `/etc/passwd` helped me (not even those from the cited [article](https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2006/10/27/cygwin-users-and-groups/)). The problem was that I was trying to install [babun](http://babun.github.io/) under Domain User but without connection to the Domain network. After connecting to the Domain network everything worked fine out of the box.

Comment: I'm on the contrary, have to disconnect the domain network and install it locally

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
mkgroup -l -d > /etc/group
```

I fixed the groups by issuing the two commands

```
mkgroup -l > /etc/group
mkgroup -c >> /etc/group
```

suggested further down in the comments of the article [Cygwin users and groups](https://sinewalker.wordpress.com/2006/10/27/cygwin-users-and-groups/).

Answer (score 0):

For me, a combination of the last two approaches worked:

1. Running `babun install` as the domain's user while in the domain, so
   that babun reinstalls.
2. Re-populating /etc/group from `mkgroup -l` and `-c`.